# Prove that $p$ is the smallest prime that divides $(p-1)!+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

By Wilson's Theorem, we know that $p$ divides $(p-1)!+1$.

Assume there exists another prime $d$ dividing $(p-1)!+1$ and $d<p$.

Then $(p-1)!\equiv-1\mod(d)$.

**I am not sure if I am right in the following statement:**

Thus, $d$ is not a factor of $(p-1)!$, which means $d$ is not any of the $\{1,2,...,p-1\}$ and this contradicts with the fact that $d<p$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct, and a slightly different approach (which ammounts to the same you wrote)

Hints:

(1)  Wilson's Theorem

(2) For any prime $\;q\;,\;\;q<p\;$ , we have that $\;q\mid (p-1)!\implies q\nmid \left[(p-1!+1\right]\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this question in a test: I solved it like this, but i'm not sure if it is correct.

By Wilson's, p divides (p-1)!+1.

Suppose another prime, p' divides (p-1)!+1. We must have that, p∤(p-1)!, otherwise, because it divides (p-1)!+1, we would have that p|1, absurd, since p≠+-1.

The above implies that p'>(p-1), because every integer from 1 to (p-1) (inclusive) is a factor of (p-1)!. then p'≥ p.

Comment: Nicely said, but you might be interested in [posting with mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).